# Search Bar Not Functioning on Django site

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-urls

I am doing a Django project and on my localhost site, I created a search bar on the site. However, that search bar doesn't return any results when given input. I viewed the page source and I noticed some lines that I never put in:

```
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value=(deleted for security purposes on Stack Overflow />
```

I then used the Inspect Element feature on my Firefox browser on Ubuntu and when I ran the Network Monitor after refreshing the page, I got this:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/css/default.css [HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED 5ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js [HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED 8ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/js/ajax.js [HTTP/1.0 304 NOT MODIFIED 11ms]
```

When I entered in some input, I got this line:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/search/ [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 13ms]
```

Here is my ajax.js file:

```
$(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/articles/search/",
            data: {
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : 
                $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

In my urls.py file, I have this line that enables searching:

```
url(r'^search/', 'article.views.search_titles'),
```

And in my views.py file, I have this search_titles function:

```
def search_titles(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
    else:
        search_text = ''

    articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)

    return render_to_response('ajax_search.html', {'articles' : articles})
```

I don't know what I'm doing to cause the search bar to not work but let me know if you need to see more of my source code and I will edit this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `url` rule should be

`url(r'^articles/search/', 'article.views.search_titles'),`

not

`url(r'^search/', 'article.views.search_titles'),`

You need to append `"articles"` in order to match your url ajax call `"/articles/search/"`

Comment: @brown1001 if this answer helped you, you can mark as correct answer clicking over the check. thanks.